# Linked Bootstrap datetimepickers, how to select only end date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using linked bootstrap datetimepickers with my project. I use those so that user can select a time range of events to search from the db, like: "select all events which have happened between start date and end date". All works well when user selects either only start date or both start date and end date.

Problems start when user want's to select only end date, like: "select all events which have happened before end date". When the end date is selected, datetimepicker fills also start date field with the same date chosen as the end date. As a result, user has to empty the start date field for the search to work before hitting the submit button.

I could unlink the pickers but then I would have to check faulty date selections elsewhere (e.g. end date before start date), and that's not very nice either. So, I'm quite uncertain how to proceed with this.

The javascript is pretty much copypaste from datetimepicker's website:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'fi',
        stepping: '15',
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
    });
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'fi',
        stepping: '15',
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
        useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
    });
    $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#datetimepicker2").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is so typical. I solved it minutes after posting this question.

The problem happened only when selecting earlier date than current date as end date. When I added useCurrent: false to datetimepicker1, the problem went away.